# Show that $\int_0^{a} e^{1/x}x^p dx $ diverges for all $p$

Tags: real-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to solve this problem using the convergence test: noting that for $a \ge 1 $ we have $0 \le e^{1/x} \le e^{1/x}x^p$ on the interval $[0,a]$ and so $\int_0^{a} e^{1/x} dx \le \int_0^{a} e^{1/x}x^p dx$. The integral on the left diverges since $e^{1/x}$ is unbounded and positive on this interval, so $\int_0^{a} e^{1/x}x^p dx$ must also diverge ($\forall p$). However, the comparison test doesn't seem to achieve this generality for $a < 1$ since $0 \le x^p \le e^{1/x}x^p$ and $\int_0^a x^pdx$ diverges for all $p \le -1$. Is there another approach to showing this result that does not involve breaking $[0,a]$ into 2 cases? Is there a modification of my argument that will work?

Comment: do you mean as $a \to \infty$?

Comment: No, $a \in \mathbb{R}$ is a fixed number. I'm just breaking up the interval $[0,a]$ so that I can make arguments using the comparison test.

Comment: The only interval of interest is $[0,1]$ because $\int_{0}^{1} e^{\frac{1}{x}}dx$ diverges

Comment: That's if, as you say, the upper bound is finite

Comment: I see so if $a < 1$ then $\int_0^a e^{1/x}dx = \int_0^1 e^{1/x}dx - \int_a^1 e^{1/x}dx$, and we have the result.

Comment: My point is that $\lim_{t \to 0} \int_{t}^{a} e^{\frac{1}{x}} dx$ doesn't exist

Comment: For $any$ a, finite or not

Comment: What I think you should look at, is whether $x^p$ term changes anything (probably not). Look at $\lim_{x \to 0} e^{\frac{1}{x}}x^p$ for example.

Comment: Can you give more precise reasoning why that limit does not exist and also why this fact shows what I wanted to prove? I'm having a good bit of confusion with convergence and divergence of improper integrals.

Comment: That limit is indeterminate, even with repeated use of L'Hospital's rule.

Comment: RHS limit is $\infty$. As for the integral, IBP p times (is p an integer?). Long story short, show that it diverges for any $a>0$.

Comment: We are interested in the behaviour of $\int_{\epsilon}^a f(x)\,dx$ for small positive $\epsilon$. Things may become more familiar if you make the change of variable $t=1/x$.

Comment: Ok that was a great hint. Under the transformation we have convergence correct? And it makes sense why if the transformed integral converges then the original diverges, but is there a way to make this rigorous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose $n> p+1.$ Then $$e^{1/x} = 1 + 1/x +\cdots 1/(n!x^n) + \cdots > 1/(n!x^n) \implies e^{1/x}x^p > 1/(n!x^{n-p}) > 1/(n!x)$$ for $0<x<1.$ Since $\int_0^1(1/x)\,dx = \infty,$ we have $\int_0^1e^{1/x}x^p\,dx=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

You just need to notice that:
$$ \int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{1/x}x^p\,dx \geq \frac{1}{(n+1)^p}\int_{\frac{1}{n+1}}^{\frac{1}{n}}e^{1/x}\,dx \geq \frac{e^n}{n(n+1)^{p+1}}$$
and the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^n}{n(n+1)^p}$ cannot be convergent since $\frac{e^n}{n(n+1)^{p+1}}$ grows unbounded as $n\to +\infty$.